# xAxis labels refuse to align with columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]
here is the configuration code: http://pastebin.com/3W3r9sHQ
apologies for the formatting but it is generated rather than written

I would like the labels to align with the columns and to be able to add my own labels which I think can be done with categories

Comment: How are you generating the configuration? The configuration for `series` seems to be the issue.

Comment: Using one of the OOP PHP libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting each point to a different series !!! It should be a single series with multiple points to get things right. You will also need to define an xAxis that contains all the x values in the correct order.

```
"xAxis": {
        "categories": [
            'Core i7-3770 4-Core 3.4GHz',
            'Core 2 Duo E4600 2.4GHz',
            'Pentium Dual Core E2200 2.2GHz'
            ]
 }
```

Set all the values into the `data` array with y value and the color

```
    "series": [{
        "type": "column",
        "name": "Popular CPU",
        "data": [
            {
            "color": "#AA4643",    
            "y": 100},
        {
            "color": "#4572A7",
            "y": 13.24},
        {
            "color": "#AA4643",
            "y": 12.03}
        ]
    }]
```

[demo basic @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/4bt4G/)
[demo @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/wahmn/)

Comment: @arcanine happy to help :) I highly recommend going through the highchart api reference, it is well written with some great live examples